# What does 必要最小限にお願いします。 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 必要最小限にお願いします。

I can't translate it at all, what could it mean ? "Please, do what's necessary" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「必要最小限{ひつようさいしょうげん}」 means "bare minimum".

> "Please keep it at a bare minimum."

Depending on the context you found this sentence in, you might need to change the "keep it" part.  Remember that Japanese is an ***extremely*** contextual language.

If I were to borrow your TL "Please, do what's necessary.", I would change it to:

> "Please do only what's absolutely necessary."

Comment: sometimes also expressed as 必要最低限

Comment: @kandyman  In my opinion, 必要最低限 implies a person should do no less than Y percent, which is more objective and related to quality. Someone set the necessary amount and you need to achieve it. In English word, it's like essential. I assume 必要最小限 is more subjective. you can set the necessary amount you want.

Comment: ”kimi Tanaka" you mean it's like a minimum target? I'm not quite sure I get your point about quality. If it's a necessary amount, then we're talking quantity, right?

Comment: @kandyman Sorry, you are correct. I mean quantity and quality.